# Can I use two identical bluetooth modules in the same area?

Tags: bluetooth

The modules I'm planning on using are the BlueSMiRF Silver Modem's shown here... http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10269.

I got one of them to work successfully but I want to make sure I can use two within the same area before I buy another one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. They aren't completely totally identical. They have different MAC addresses, same as two of the same network cards.

Comment: NO doubt the correct answer

Comment: @ppumkin, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Kortuk- `No Doubt` - If i answered this thread my answer would be the same  `the correct answer` imply that the answer can not get any better- deserves an up vote and most likely will be accepted as the only answer.

Comment: +1, the only thing I would add is that some network devices/chips require the MAC id to be provided by hardware separate from the device. I'm not familiar with BlueSmirf